# Java Threadpool handle unlimited queued threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

im testing my Server which has a threadpool for the connections.

```
public class Test
{
    public static final void main(String[] args)
    {
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutorSentMessage = new ThreadPoolExecutor(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(),
                    100,
                    5,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

        ConnctionListener con = new ConnctionListener() //ignore this, included it for other usage.
        {
            public void onStartSendingMessages()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                    {
                        threadPoolExecutorSentMessage.execute(new TestT("Message: " + i));
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        con.onStartSendingMessages();

        //new Thread(new MessageConnectionWaiter(con)).start();
    }




    private static class TestT implements Runnable
    {
        private String msg;

        public TestT(String msg)
        {
            this.msg = msg;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Its not the server code, but im testing with the code how the threads working.
When im starting unlimited threads(like many connections to my server), there is a problem, that its stuck and nothing happens. I though that the threadpool is blocking new tasks, before the threadpool has avaiable space for a new thread. Can someone tell how to handle something like this? I tried to reduce the amount of max. threads but it dont fixed my problem. I just want that the threadpool runs thread no matter how much threads are waiting.

Comment: It's probably stuck because the console of your IDE can't keep adding text forever, and because the memory is a finite resource and thus can't contain an infinity of tasks.

Comment: Its printing about 50 times, after it stuck. And for this purpose i have thread pool or not ? The thread is limiting the amount of threads are running.

Comment: I already told you why I think it's stuck. And I have no idea what you're asking by "for this purpose i have thread pool or not ?". Add a Thread.sleep(1000) at each iteration of your while loop, ad clear the console after each batch, and you should se that it runs forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the number of threads causing the problem. It is the number of tasks you are adding to the workqueue. You are adding the tasks in a infinite loop. And work queue has a capacity, the linked queue has maximum capacity of Integer.MAX_VALUE. After you have added that many tasks, the main thread start waiting for the space to be emptied in work queue. After your threadpools thread  complete  execution of any task and removes the task from the queue, the space becomes available and main thread can add the task only if there is any space for the task in the queue

Comment: the queue is just getting full, and thats why the task "stopping"

Comment: You can verify using the threadPoolExecutorSentMessage.getTaskCount(), you will get idea of active tasks after some time.

Comment: The tasks are not stopping it is just the task submission to the queue are put on hold until some space is available in the worker queue